# How Can I install Java on mac

Tags: mac, java

I want to install java plug-in in firefox .

I read that installing java plug-in is not secure.

**EDIT1** : **Can anyone please tell me why java installation is not secure, and should I install it or not.**

Comment: WHere did you "read that installing java plug-in is not secure"

Comment: on Mozilla's official site.

Comment: Can you quote the actual info - note that I think it is wrong - mozilla might be insecure but Java is not as it has been patched

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2030778/researchers-javas-security-problems-unlikely-to-be-resolved-soon.html

Comment: @Mark I am not saying Java is insecure. I read that some malicious site can do some stuff if your browser has java plug-in installed.

Comment: @TLE which is the defintion of insecure surely. The reason I ask for the exact quote is that the issue is time dependent -

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5988800/what-is-java-is-it-insecure-and-should-i-use-it

Comment: What @Mark is saying the last discovered security hole was plugged.

Comment: Let's temporarily close this as a duplicate and see if there is really a second distinct question here. We can merge the answers if this really is a continued discussion on Java security

Answer (score 1):

**Download and install Java from [java.com](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp).**

---

If it doesn't seem to work, check if it is installed using [Java Tester](http://javatester.org/version.html). If it only doesn't work in Firefox, make sure that the Java plugin is enabled in the Add-ons Manager tab:

1. On the menu bar, click on the **Tools** menu, and then click **Add-ons**. The Add-ons Manager tab will open.
2. In the Add-ons Manager tab, select the **Plugins** panel.
3. Click on the **Java Applet Plug-in** to select it.
4. Select **Always Activate** in its drop-down menu if it's not already set.

Answer (score 0):

No nontrivial software is absolutely secure, at least when it is exposed to the Internet. Rather, software security is a relative term: Some software is more secure, other software less so.

As for java, when run as a plugin in the browser, I think it is safe to say that its security record has been rather abysmal. There have been many security holes, and though all publicly known security holes have been patched as far as I know, history does not inspire confidence.

Since you use firefox, you can improve your security somewhat by enabling `plugins.click_to_play`. If you do, all plugins such as flash and java will be disabled on every web page you visit until you click on the plugin to allow it to run.

To enable this feature, type `about:config` in the Firefox address bar and hit return. You may get a warning. Take it seriously! Messing around in `about:config` without knowing what you're doing can really ruin your setup. Anyhow, find the option `plugins.click_to_play` in the list – there is a handy search box that you can use – and double click the line to toogle the value between false and true.

See also [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87784/how-safe-is-it-for-me-to-install-java-on-os-x-10-8), which I noticed after writing the above.