# Is Java 6 on Mavericks safe to use?

Tags: macos, security, java

I have some web applications (java applets) which have trouble running with Java 7 and java 64 bit.

The tech support wants me to install Java 6 and disable Java 7, here are the instructions:

> 1. Please download and install the Java update named "JavaForOSX2013-05.dmg" from Apple for better security. For OS X 10.7 and above: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572
> 2. After that, please follow the instructions below to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start functionality: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

Security-wise, is it safe to setup OS X this way?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? "Safe" as in "does it break anything", as in "does it open any security holes" or something else?

Comment: @patrix : I mean from a security standpoint. I guess the tags are not enough to make it clear.

Comment: I didn't look at the tags (hmm), thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is safe in security terms, all that you can say is that there is a risk and try to quantify it.

For Java there are often exploits for Java applets and at some time Apple found that they and Oracle could not produce a fix quick enough to stop a well known exploit. Apple then put out a change to Safari to block all Java applets if the Java version was below a given version and this version limit is increased regularly.

The latest Apple-provided Java installer as of 17 Oct 2014 is [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572). It fixes the vulnerabilities listed [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5982) by providing a version of Java version 1.6.0_65.

Also see this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87823/237)

There will be vulnerabilities in that but Apple have so far decided none of those known to them are serious enough to block the use of this version or produce a new version.